# Binding elements of array in a view

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm new to aurelia framework. I'm trying to create a list of text inputs with inline edit. Every input should be disabled by default and after clicking on edit button it should be able to edit by removing `disbaled` attribute.

My welcome.js:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(HttpClient)
export class Welcome {
    heading =  'Welcome';

    inputs_list = [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'text': 'example one',
            'edit': false
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'text': 'example two',
            'edit': false
        },
    ];

    editInput(evt){
        let input = this.inputs_list.find( input => input.id === id );
        input.edit = true;
    }

}
```

My view file welcome.html:

```
<template>
    ${heading}
    <ul>
        <li repeat.for="input of inputs_list">
            <input ${input.edit ? '' : 'disabled'} type="text" value="${input.text}" class="inputs"/>
            <input type="button" click.delegate="editInput(input.id)" value="edit" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

And I'm getting a warn:

```
WARN [templating-binding] Unknown binding command. Object {defaultBindingMode: null, attrName: "${input", attrValue: "", command: "edit", expression: null}
```

I have already found solution by modifying `editInput` method and passing `$event` as a parameter:

```
editInput(evt){
    let inputs = evt.target.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('inputs');
    Array.from(inputs).forEach( input => input.removeAttribute('disabled') );

}
```

It works but I'd like to know what is the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aurelia is getting confused b/c there's no attribute on `input` elements called `${input.edit ? '' : 'disabled'}`. You need to use the binding command to bind to the disabled attribute.

It might help you to read through some getting started guides on how to work with Aurelia's binding engine. For example `value="${input.text}"` probably is not doing what you want it to do. To have the `input.text` property bound to the value of that textbox, you need to use `value.bind="input.text"`.

Also, in the `click` handler, you can simply pass the item from the array instead of passing its id. `click.delegate="editInput(input)"` and then set the `input.edit` property to true in the `editInput` function. Alternatively, you could just do this inline in your view, as I have shown below.

Finally, `inputs_list` doesn't follow standard JavaScript naming conventions. You may want to consider switching to `inputsList` or `inputList` as I have shown below:

**Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=69bfe207db225125237878ebd7caccd8**

**app.html**

```html
<template>
    ${heading}
    <ul>
        <li repeat.for="input of inputList">
            <input disabled.bind="!input.edit" type="text" value.bind="input.text" class="inputs"/>
            <input type="button" click.delegate="input.edit = true" value="edit" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Welcome {
    heading =  'Welcome';

    inputList = [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'text': 'example one',
            'edit': false
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'text': 'example two',
            'edit': false
        },
    ];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a value directly to the attribute like this:

```
<input disabled.bind="input.edit" type="text" value="${input.text}" class="inputs"/>
```

This way you won't have to fiddle with DOM queries or tinker with the attributes directly

Check out this article for more [information](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-basics/1)